# UAC Elevation is Always Occurring Based on Installing User

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

I have certain application installers run at system startup via a Startup Script GPO (which runs as SYSTEM).

When the install is completed as SYSTEM in this way, running the installed exe (C:\MyApp\App.exe) always prompts for UAC elevation. Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers for the exe in both HKLM and HKCU are not present and I've even tried explicitly setting to RUNASINVOKER. I've also verified that in the Compatibility tab in the UI, Run as Administrator is NOT checked.

Despite this, the exe always prompts for UAC elevation.

If I install the app as a local administrator (and accept the elevation prompt during the install), the exe does NOT prompt for UAC elevation after install (even when it is subsequently run by a non-Administrator user).

I've reviewed the documentation on different causes for UAC elevation and this does not appear to be related to any of them. I've tried explicitly changing the install folder and exe's owner from SYSTEM to Everyone, but this has no effect.

What's going on here?

UPDATE: additional clue - if I rename the MyApp.exe to MyApp1.exe file after install, it no longer prompts for elevation. This would make me suspect that it's a compatibility assistance registry setting, but there is none present at Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers in both HKLM and HKCU...so what's up?

Comment: Do you have UAC turned OFF?  UAC will always prompt even for Administrator (but in this case will not ask for credentials).  Some apps installed as System are run by Task Scheduler with elevated privileges. Is that the case here?

Comment: @john - yes uac is on and I would like to keep it that way. The app was indeed installed as SYSTEM, but it has no need to and should not run with any elevation after that. 

However, if the app is installed as SYSTEM, it always subsequently prompts for elevation which I do NOT want

Comment: It may be a function the particular application as most applications work as I suggested above

Comment: Right, ok, how to I stop it from elevating? And why does it not elevate if installed by a user instead of SYSTEM?

Comment: It is not a standard operating system thing, so you must ask the software vendor.

Comment: That’s not true. The Windows clearly does something different based on who installed the user. It must have to do with the ACLs or something in the registry that indicates the app is owner by SYSTEM and cannot be run as a regular user. (Like the TrustedInstaller owned dlls in Windows)

Comment: I mean it is definitely something related to the software vendor, but there is no way they’ll change their product and there is clearly some setting in Windows that controls the behavior

Comment: All the software we use follows the normal install rules unless it is truly system software. Is it a service? You can change the service owner in Services. We need to do that for the QuickBooks Server Manager

Comment: It’s just a normal exe for a GUI WinForms looking application. The only difference between when it always prompts for elevation or not is whether the software is installed/setup.exe is run by SYSTEM as a startup script vs. interactively by a local administrator.